# Set-AzureSubscription : Cannot bind parameter 'Certificate' becuase of illegal characters error

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

I am running this command on Windows 2012 server R2 with Azure Powershell

I am using following code for setting azure subscription

```
C:\PS>$subID = <Subscription ID>
C:\PS>$thumbprint = <Certificate Thumbprint>
```

Getting certificate thumbprint contain using

```
C:\PS>$myCert = Get-Item cert:\\CurrentUser\My\$thumbprint | Out-String
C:\PS>Set-AzureSubscription –SubscriptionName $subID –SubscriptionId $subID –Certificate `"$myCert`"
```

But it is failing with following error

```
Set-AzureSubscription : Cannot bind parameter 'Certificate'. Error: can't convert illegal characters
```

I have also tried with following code

```
C:\PS>$myCert = Get-Item cert:\\CurrentUser\My\$thumbprint
C:\PS>Set-AzureSubscription –SubscriptionName $subID –SubscriptionId $subID –Certificate $myCert
```

Still it is failing with error Cannot bind parameter 'Certificate'

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just tried last 2 lines of code from your question and it worked fine for me. If I do the following `$myCert = Get-Item cert:\\CurrentUser\My\$thumbprint | Out-String`, then I get the same error as you're getting. Can you please try again.

Comment: I have tried this again it is failing with following error
Set-AzureSubscription : Cannot bind parameter 'Certificate'. Cannot convert
value ""
    Directory: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::CurrentUser\My
Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
A4DF95BE6410E68E360E9706316F6EF542172796  CN=AmarCert
"" to type "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2".
Error: "Illegal characters in path."

Answer (score 2):

You should stop using certificates for Azure PowerShell auth and start using AAD. This works for both the Azure Service Management and Azure Resource Manager modes of PowerShell.

Add-AzureAccount
Select-AzureSubscription ...
Set-AzureSubscription ...

and you're done - never having to worry about certificates again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
Get-Item Cert:\CurrentUser\
```

(i.e. not cert:\\CurrentUser\ with two back slashes)